# Make python timer objects in a list start at the same point

Tags: python

I have a lot of timer objects (We're talking about 10,000+) from the threading library in a list in python. It is imperative that they all start at exactly the same time, due to the fact that each is responsible for a note on a virtual piano. If they fire at the wrong time, the song sounds out of sync and messy.

How can I ensure they all start at the same moment?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the threading module in python as that will allow parallisation, however due to GIL, its not possible to execute multiple threads at the **exact** same time on the same machine : https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: That is an utterly insane way to play music.  Sort the notes by starting time (assuming they're not already in that order), use a *single* timer or a `sleep()` to wait until the first note's time.  Start that note, and any others with the same start time, then use a timer/sleep to wait until the next note.